# Can't SSH into the Server

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I installed proftpd on my server hoping to be able to SSH into the server.

Now when I try, here is what I get

```
MacBook-Pro:~ admin$ ssh macmike@www.mikealrhughes.com
Connection closed by 24.72.189.165 port 22
```

This is running in Ubuntu 16.04 Server.

Any suggestions?

Also is there anyway to get this list to email me when I receive a reply?

Comment: May you try SSH by removing www from your address? See if it makes any difference (if so, update your post by the change)

Answer (score 1):

Install openssh-server on your server. That will provide ssh access to the server. Proftpd "only" provides ftp access.

Comment: I installed openssh-server now I just tried macmike@mikealrhughes.com:22 it asked for password once I put the password in came back with Alert Unable to connect with server, please try again later.